# How to retrieve the secrets with Service principal with certificate

Tags: azure-keyvault, x509certificate2

**Goal:** My web application in on Premise and wants to retrieve secrets from Keyvault using ServicePrincipal

Please note I can not DefaultAzureCredential as my application are not on cloud and in Azure.Idenetity it is suggested to use ClientCertificateCredential for on prem

I am trying to use Service principal with certificate for the App registered to connect to key vault and read certificate and Secrets in it.
I think i found how to get certificate which i explain but not sure how to get secert from vertificate to build ClientCertificateCredential from it
here are the steps
1- Created a local machine self registered certificate --> exported the pfx
2- Registered an app on Azure and uploaded the pfx  in there ( Created Service Principal with certificate)
3- created an azure keyvault and gave my app Secret officer role and certificate officer
4- create secret named **testSecert** with value of 1234 in the Keyvault
5- create a certificate named "kvtestcert"
6- created the **ClientCertificateCredential** using the certificate (see below code)

**a. Below code is to Access local machine store to get the certificate I created**
var x509Store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2 x509Certificate = x509Store.Certificates
.Find(
X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
azureADCertThumbprint,
validOnly: false)
.OfType()
.Single();

**b.Below code to Get the Certificate from keyvault in below**
var keyVaultUri = $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net/";

var certCredential = new ClientCertificateCredential(tenantId,
appId,
x509Certificate2);

var certificateClient = new CertificateClient(new Uri(keyVaultUri), credential);
KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy keyVaultCertificateWithPolicy =
certificateClient.Certificate(certificateName);

So far I could get the certificate inside the keyvault with myService principal.
Now i would like to use that Service principal to retrieve the Secret as well but not sure how?

**c.my problem is in below code and not sure what to pass for SecretClient**
To retrieve the secrets I need create a ClientSecertCredential and for that I need to pass SecretClient.
**please Note**: I do not want to create any secrets for my app as it is not recommended for production. I want to use certificate way

How and where to get the SecretClient to be able to use it to create ClientSecertCredential in below code
var srcrtCredential = new ClientSecertCredential(tenantId,
appId,
**SecertClient???**);
var secretClient= new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUri), srcrtCredential);

var secret = secretClient.GetSecret(secretName);

Any advice would be very much appreciated?

Comment: The application is .net 4.8

Answer (score 0):

To get a secret I use the following code:

```
var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId: _tenantId, clientId: _clientId, clientSecret: _secret);
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(_vaultUrl), credentials);

KeyVaultSecret kvSecret = client.GetSecret(_keyRingName);
```

The tenantId, ClientId and Secret I get from the app registration in AzureAD. Meaning from this JSON that I am presented with after registration:

```
{
  "clientId": "603761e0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "clientSecret": "rTU8Q~Lgxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "subscriptionId": "b78d216b-dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "tenantId": "567d82a1-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "activeDirectoryEndpointUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
  "resourceManagerEndpointUrl": "https://management.azure.com/",
  "activeDirectoryGraphResourceId": "https://graph.windows.net/",
  "sqlManagementEndpointUrl": "https://management.core.windows.net:8443/",
  "galleryEndpointUrl": "https://gallery.azure.com/",
  "managementEndpointUrl": "https://management.core.windows.net/"
}
```

Does that notwork?

Comment: Thanks for reply! The problem is that I do not want to use the application secret. I read that certificates are more secure and I want to use certificate to authenticate my application not secrets. Secrets could be used for dev and UAT but for prod I think we should use certificate.

Comment: I already know how to authenticate with certifiacte as i explained in my question . I also can use that to get the certificates in keyvault how ever I do not know how to get the secrets

Comment: Yes, you upload it as a secret to Azure key vault, but if you want the cert including the private key, you need to download it as a secret (not cert). Yes, its strange. I posted some more code here about this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74845992/azure-key-vault-download-original-pfx-from-ket-vault/74847874#74847874

Comment: Or perhaps I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Thanks for your help! How ever that is to get certificate from the Vault. I want at this point connect to Keyvault with Service Principal with Certificate not ClientSecert .For that i found that I can use the below code 

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }

Comment: I can use combination of Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration and Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets to get the secrets and set my web.config keys see the below code

Comment: I have to add code in multiple post as i do not have enough characters

Comment: //First Get cert from local store, This certificate is loaded to my app in app registration that has access to keyvault 
var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,myCertificateThumbprint, false);

Comment: //with Appid,tenantid and certificate I should be able to access keyvault
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder configBuilder = new Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder();
var builder = configBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri($"https://MyKeyvaultName.azure.net/"),  new ClientCertificateCredential(myTenantId,myClientId,certs.OfType<X509Certificate2>().Single()), new KeyVaultSecretManager());
var config = builder.Build();
foreach (var keyValuePair in config.AsEnumerable())
{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);}

Comment: The code is not working i get null , it gives me {"Sequence contains no elements"} in error

Comment: So what is your question so far? You are asking quite a lot of questions in your question above... so perhaps better to break it down into more specific questions

Comment: So when i started this question i did not know know a lot of things and now i am clear what i want. I want to make the last code that i posted to work. So i can use Service principal with certificate to access Keyvault. However i get "Sequence contains no elements"} in error and i am not sure why . There is no other info in the error, other than error code -2146233079. I expect to be able to get all the secrets in this way using this extension.configuration from the vault which is external resource .  I am kind of on dead blocked as i do not know why it is not working.

Comment: Really hard to tell how to troubleshoot it.